# polars.date_range X delta from high or low

Tags: python-polars

Is there a way of using `polars.date_range` without specifying the high or low, but instead providing X delta from the origin?

Pandas example:

`dates = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=50, freq='D')`

Comment: I don't think so - it was requested the other day https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7525

Comment: @jqurious I guess one way around is extracting values and then creating a dataframe or series with it :(

Comment: You can use `pl.select` which simplifies things - I've added an answer showing how if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [feature request open for this.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7525)

It looks like the current polars equivalent would be:

```
start = pl.lit("2000-01-01").str.strptime(pl.Datetime)

pl.select(
   pl.date_range(start, start.dt.offset_by("49d"))
)
```

```
shape: (50, 1)
┌─────────────────────┐
│ literal             │
│ ---                 │
│ datetime[μs]        │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 2000-01-01 00:00:00 │
│ 2000-01-02 00:00:00 │
│ 2000-01-03 00:00:00 │
│ 2000-01-04 00:00:00 │
│ ...                 │
│ 2000-02-16 00:00:00 │
│ 2000-02-17 00:00:00 │
│ 2000-02-18 00:00:00 │
│ 2000-02-19 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, QQ: why `pl.date_range` generates datetime variable when date was passed?

Comment: I created a datetime using `pl.Datetime` - you can use `pl.Date` instead if you want. The pandas version creates datetimes which is why I chose it.